# What is the latest standardized C++ runtime environment/software for someone who wants to pick up from where he left 9 years ago?

Tags: c++

I used to code in C++ (Borland Turbo C++ 3.0) till 2010. After that the world moved on to Windows 7, Vista, etc, where the TC 3.0 didn't really run, and I lost touch. Last week I participated in a coding contest using C++, and realized how outdated my knowledge on libraries and syntax have become! I am looking for suggestions on where to pick up and which software to install if I wish to get up-to-date with the latest standards and syntax in C++?

I currently use Windows 10 (open to operate in Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more about getting familiar with new syntax and standards in c++.

With this in mind, you will need an IDE or editor that analyse your code and makes suggestions for better ways to program.

For this purpose, I’m a huge fan of Jetbrains products. Have a look at their CLion.

Visual Studio includes IntelliSense, which is very popular and might be a good option, too. Keep in mind though, that Visual Studio does things different than the standard sometimes.

Comment: I have to agree, if you dopn't mind paying for it, nothing beats a JetBrains IDE (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), and also Google for the new Windows 10 Bash shell, which ought to also have the GCC and G++ compilers (something like pthis]( https://developerinsider.co/compile-cpp-program-with-gplusplus-compiler-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10/)). Don’t forget [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), either.

But the simplest way is to get the free [MS Visual](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/whatsnew/) Studio or [MS Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).